# PHP - If one or more allowed values in one array are in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:$user_level and $allowed_levels

What is the best way to check if the $user_level array contains one or more of the array items that are in $allowed_level ?

The code can be seen here:

```
$user_level = array('Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level 4', 'Level 5');

$allowed_levels = array('Level 1', 'Level 2');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array_diff function will create an array of values that are not present in both arrays. You can then check if this is empty or not. If it is not empty then this will mean $user_levels contains one or more of the $allowed_level array items:

```
 $user_level = array('Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level 4', 'Level 5');
 $allowed_levels = array('Level 1', 'Level 2');
 $result = array_diff($user_level, $allowed_levels)

 if(!(empty($result)){
    **Code if it is not empyy**
 }
```

Comment: I like this, is there not an error with your 'if is not empty'? For example what happens if $user_level contains nothing? Ex: if( !empty($result) && count($result) > 0 ) {

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$result = array_intersect($user_level,$allowed_levels);
```

Then compare $allowed_levels with $result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I suggest:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach ($user in $user_level)
{
if(in_array($user,$allow_levels)
{
$count.=1;
}
}
echo 'There were ' . $count . ' matches';

?>
```